# Basis for the quotient space.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $U$ be a subspace of a finite dimensional $F$ - vector space $V$ with $dim U = k$ and $dimV=n$. Prove that if $\mathscr B_U = \{\vec v_1, \dots, \vec v_k \} $ is a basis for $U$ and $\mathscr B_V = \{\vec v_1, \dots, \vec v_k, \vec v_{k+1}, \dots, \vec v_n \} $ is a basis for V, then
$$\mathscr B_{V/U} = \{\vec v_{k+1} +U, \dots, \vec v_n + U \}$$ is a basis for $V/U$.

Solution: Assume $$B_{V/U} = \{\vec v_{k+1} +U, \dots, \vec v_n + U \}$$ is a basis. Then $ c_{k+1}(\vec v_{k+1} +U) + \dots + c_n(\vec v_n + U)= 0 +U \implies$

$(c_{k+1}\vec v_{k+1} + \dots + c_n\vec v_n ) + U= 0 +U$.
We can rewrite vector $c_{k+1}\vec v_{k+1} + \dots + c_n\vec v_n $ as a linear combination of vectors from $\mathscr B_U$. So we will get:

$c_{k+1}\vec v_{k+1} + \dots + c_n\vec v_n = c_1\vec v_1 + \dots + c_k \vec v_k$, $\implies$ $ c_1\vec v_1 + \dots + c_k \vec v_k - (c_{k+1}\vec v_{k+1} + \dots + c_n\vec v_n ) = 0$ and since vectors $ \vec v_1, \dots, \vec v_k, \vec v_{k+1}, \dots, \vec v_n$ form a basis for the space $V$, they are linearly independent. So $c_1=\dots=c_k=c_{k+1}=\dots=c_n=0$. Thus the equation $(c_{k+1}\vec v_{k+1} + \dots + c_n\vec v_n ) + U= 0 +U$ will have only trivial solution for $c_{k+1}=\dots=c_n=0$ and vectors $\vec v_{k+1} +U, \dots, \vec v_n + U$ will be linearly independent. Therefore, $\mathscr B_{V/U}$ form a basis for $ U/V$.

Comment: You've shown that the set $\mathscr B_{V/U} = {\vec v_{k+1} +U, \dots, \vec v_n + U }$ is linearly independent, and since there are $n-k$ vectors in this set, the dimension of $V/U$ is $n-k$. Thus, $\mathscr B_{V/U}$ forms a basis for $V/U$

Comment: @rumathe Thank you!!!!

Comment: You cannot start the proof by saying “Assume $\mathscr{B}_{V/U}$ is a basis”, this is what you want to prove!  And you only proved that $\mathscr{B}_{V/U}$ is linearly independent. You also need to prove that every element of $V/U$ can be written as a linear combination of the elements of $\mathscr{B}_{V/U}$. If you already know that $\dim(V/U)=n-k$, then you can skip this, but you need to say it in your proof.